# I can't open an iPhone simulator. The Android version works fine

Tags: iphone, android-studio, flutter, simulator

The console looks like this:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             29,8s
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           330,1s

Configuring the default Firebase app...
6.33.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000004] App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT does not exist.
6.33.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
*** First throw call stack:

(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2041daf2 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177e78 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2041d9d0 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
    3   Runner                              0x0000000103bf2c42 +[FIRApp configure] + 130
    4   Runner                              0x0000000103c4a603 -[FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin init] + 259
    5   Runner                              0x0000000103c4a356 +[FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin registerWithRegistrar:] + 70
    6   Runner                              0x0000000103bf2673 +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 115
    7   Runner
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message specifically says that it can't locate the Google service json file.
Make sure you follow the instructions properly and just a tip for ios, drag and drop the Google service json file doesn't work like Android.
You should drag and drop the Google service json file through xcode and add it to ios application directory.

Comment: But I don’t use Firebase at all? I just use ad mob... I thought I could use ad mob without linking it to firebase..

Comment: I don't really think you can do that without having a firebase project setup.